# Yii2 RBAC Redis - whats wrong?

Tags: redis, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, rbac, yii2-rbac

I`m tryind to use **RBAC** in my Yii2 advanced app (**sweelix/yii2-redis-rbac** and **yiisoft/yii2-redis** is installed).

1. common/main.php:

   ```
   //....
   'components' => [
       'authManager' => [
           'class' => 'sweelix\rbac\redis\Manager',
           'db' => 'redis',
       ],
       // ...
   ],
   ```
2. common/main-local.php:

   ```
   //....
   'components' => [
       'authManager' => [
           'class' => 'yii\redis\Connection',
           'hostname' => 'localhost',
           'port' => 6379,
           'database' => 1,
       ],
       // ...
   ],
   ```
3. Let`s try to init (RbacController):

   ```
   public function actionInit()
   {
       $auth->removeAll();
       $user = $auth->createRole('user');
       $auth->add($user);

       $admin = $auth->createRole('admin');
       $auth->add($admin);

       $auth->addChild($admin, $user);
       $auth->assign($admin, 1); // 1 - is id of admin user on database }
   ```

`php yii rbac/init` return:

```
Error: Redis error: ERR wrong number of arguments for 'hget' command. Redis command was: HGET auth:mappings:rules
```

Dump of object:

```
    $user = $auth->createRole('user');
    var_dump($user);die;
```

returns:

```
    object(yii\rbac\Role)#21 (7) {
      ["type"]=> int(1)
      ["name"]=> string(4) "user"
      ["description"]=> NULL
      ["ruleName"]=> NULL
      ["data"]=> NULL
      ["createdAt"]=> NULL
      ["updatedAt"]=> NULL
    }
```

**sweelix\rbac\redisManager** at line **364**:
If $item->ruleName is null we have error...

```
$ruleGuid = $this->db->executeCommand('HGET', [$this->getRuleMappingKey(), $item->ruleName]);
```

Vers.:

`Redis server v=3.2.6`,
`"yiisoft/yii2": "~2.0.14"`,
`yiisoft/yii2-redis 2.0.8`,
`PHP 7.0.33`

Answer (score 1):

I checked it in other applications and environments and noticed that it works on version `"yiisoft/yii2-redis": "2.0.8"` and on `"yiisoft/yii2-redis": "2.0.9"` it gives an error (**sweelix\rbac\redisManager** at line **364**: 
`$ruleGuid = $this->db->executeCommand('HGET', [$this->getRuleMappingKey(), $item->ruleName]);`). 
If you forcefully switch to the "**2.0.8**" version of the package the error disappears.